# Serverless-framework & next.js lambda function exceeds unpacked size limit

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda, next.js, server-side-rendering, serverless-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the package size of a ssr application (next.js & serverless-framework) to get it under 250MB AWS limit: `An error occurred: ServerLambdaFunction - Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400;` The app is deployed by running `next build && sls deploy`

The unpacked archive is 600MB+, more than double of 250MB that AWS allows for lambda. Below is the list of largest dependencies in node_modules. I can see that i can reduce it marginally by moving several to dev dependencies, but that won't solve the problem.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

[image: node modules with largest size]

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ssr-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "next build",
    "deploy": "next build && sls deploy",
    "start": "next start",
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^3.2.4",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.4.4",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^3.5.4",
    "@aws-amplify/storage": "^3.3.4",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.21",
    "antd": "^4.6.4",
    "antd-img-crop": "^3.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "country-state-picker": "^1.1.1",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.16",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "next": "^9.5.3",
    "next-react-svg": "^1.1.2",
    "path-match": "^1.2.4",
    "query-string": "^6.13.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-share": "^4.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^4.2.0",
    "serverless-http": "^2.5.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

my serverless.yml is:

```
service: ssr-react-next

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-2
  stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}

functions:
  server:
    handler: index.server
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
  customDomain:
    domainName: ${self:custom.secrets.DOMAIN}
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is aws lambda limit of 250MB, but you can try using `useServerlessTraceTarget: true` in serverless.yml it should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to solve your problem:

1. Move `dependencies` that are not used during runtime to `devDependencies`.

Serverless ignores `devDependencies` when it's creating the zip file to upload.

2. Add `aws-sdk` to `devDependencies`.

Until Node.js v16, `aws-sdk` `v2` is already available in Lambda. So don't bundle it.

Also, if you are using Node.js v18, better to update to latest version of AWS SDK (`@aws-ask/*`)

3. Since you are using `webpack` bundler, you can package your functions individually.

That means, serverless shall create an individual zip file for each lambda function.

You can enable that by having the below in your `serverless.yml` file:

```
package:
  individually: true
```

4. Ignore files that do not have to be in the zip file

You can do that by having the below in your `serverless.yml` file:

```
package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - '!.github'
    - '!.husky'
    - '!node_modules/aws-sdk/**'
    - '!node_modules/@aws-sdk/**'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!README.md'
```

You can add more patterns depending on your use-cases.